# WCFService гарантированная доставка сообщений

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Подскажите решение, есть WCF-сервис с RabbitMQ  и клиенты(мобильные устройства), на которых отправляются сообщения. Нужно чтобы чтобы клиент гарантированно получал сообщения отправляемые сервисом, после того как он появится в сети. Подскажите как это можно реализовать?

Comment: На клиентах есть ваше приложение ?

Comment: @Sam_Fisher Да. И WCF и клиент - собственной разработки.

Comment: Делайте тогда коллбэк с клиента о том что сообщение пришло.
После того как с клиента пришло подтверждение о том что сообщение пришло, переводите статус сообщения в отправленный.
На мобильнике надо проверять статус сети и если можно, то обращаемся к сервису за сообщениями, которые в статусе не отправленны.

Comment: @Sam_Fisher да была такая идея. Но вообще, желательно конечно PUSH сообщениями. Зачем клиенту постоянно посылать запросы на сервер, если для него нет ничего.

Comment: Ставьте Signal-R тогда =), правда держать соединения на 1000-ххх клиентов довольно расходная операция, зато получается пуш =)
На сервере что то появилось, на телефон сразу отправилось сообщение.

Comment: @Sam_Fisher, на данный момент, 1000 не планируется. Спасибо за подсказку.  Т.е Signal-R постоянно будет держать связь мобильного приложения и WCF?

Answer (score 1):

Ставьте Signal-R, он постоянно держит соединение с сервером, так что со стороны сервера можно будет послать клиенту сообщение.

WCF вам не нужен будет.

Comment: Но WCF служит в качестве backend.

Comment: Вам никто не мешает использовать WCF вместе с Signal-R сервисом.